# Core Data Fetch Result Crash "Attempt to create two animations for cell"

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, core-data, swiftui

using core data i'm storing some airport info and for every airport i'm saving different note

I have created the entity Airport and the entity Briefing

Airport have 1 attribute called icaoAPT and Briefing have 4 attribute category, descript, icaoAPT, noteID

in order to divide the note by section on my FilterListView I use the func update to sort the list

but some time when I exit from the view app crash, give me the error "Attempt to create two animations for cell"

```
struct FilterLIst: View {
    var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<Briefing>
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var dbContext
    
    
    init(filter: String) {
        fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Briefing>(entity: Briefing.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "airportRel.icaoAPT == %@", filter))
        
    }

        func update(_ result : FetchedResults<Briefing>) -> [[Briefing]] {
           let dic = Dictionary(grouping: result) { (Sequence: Briefing) in
                 Sequence.category
           }.values.map{$0}
            return dic
            
            }

        
  
    var body: some View {
      
        List{
            ForEach(update(self.fetchRequest.wrappedValue), id: \.self) { section in
                Section(header: Text(section[0].category ?? "NOT AVAILABLE")) {
                    self.categoryView(section: section)
                }
            }
        }
       
    }
    
    func categoryView(section: [Briefing]) -> some View {
        ForEach(section, id: \.self) { briefing in
            Text(briefing.descript ?? "NOT AVAIL")
        }
    }
}
```

reading online this error could be created because on the func update , after map I should use .sorted(by: ) //  avoid crashes!

my question is, how I can use sorted on my code.. and why this happen? can't understand what sorted does..

thanks for the help